# Software to manage digital assets

Tags: storage, media

Over the years I have accumulated enough digital assets (mainly videos and photos) for it to become a massive problem in terms of organizing it all and then being able to find it.

I am wondering what people are using out there, regardless of the platform (even though I am deeply invested on Linux)

Here are the requirements I consider essential:

1. Being able to identify duplicates and save storage
2. Ability to apply multiple tags and comments to make searching easier
3. Ability to "publish" or otherwise make visible through a controlled web server only a subset of these assets
4. Easy way to export or otherwise create backup copies
5. Intuitive GUI front end

I have been searching around without any luck so I am keen to hear from other in this forum.

Comment: I recently discovered that what I should look for is DAM Software. Digital Asset Management/

Answer (score 1):

Adobe provide two useful sidekick tools to manage video filles.

[Adobe Bridge](https://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html) is a digital asset management app fully efficient with photo and video.

[Adobe Media Encoder](https://www.adobe.com/products/media-encoder.html) is a is professional video converter with watch folder options, and ProRes support for Windows and Mac.

These software are not available on Linux, but their [metadata](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unix%20adobe%20bridge&t=brave&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clonefileschecker.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F10%2Fimage1.jpg) and files are useful on every modern system.